# How to get column and row Index of each element in big GridPane(15x15)

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, gridpane

I want to find the best solution for getting the column and row index of many elements in cells.

For example I have GridPane(15x15). Each cell has Button component. I want to get index of row and column when mouseClicked event is indicated. I know how to do this manually:

```
@FXML Button btn1;

btn1.setOnMouseClicked(e->{
            System.out.println("Row: "+ GridPane.getRowIndex(btn1));
            System.out.println("Column: "+ GridPane.getColumnIndex(btn1));
        });
```

But what to do this in my problem: 15x15 gridPane. It's not effective to declare every button and copying the same code for each component. Someone has a idea how to do this?

//============================================================

I have decided to prepare one method and link it to all button. It what I was looking for :).

Thanks for answer

```
    @FXML 
        private void testClicked(MouseEvent e){
            Node src = (Node)e.getSource();
            System.out.println("Row: "+ GridPane.getRowIndex(src));
            System.out.println("Column: "+ GridPane.getColumnIndex(src));
}
```

Comment: Maybe this answer can help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24715911/javafx-adding-button-to-grid-pane

Comment: It's not clear why your code would need to be repetitive. Can you post some more code showing what you are doing? Are you defining all 225 buttons in FXML? Or can you just define the grid pane in FXML and define the buttons in the controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just loop through all elements of your `GridPane` and add your Eventhandler there.

```
    for (Node element : gridpane.getChildren()) {
        element.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                System.out.println("Row: " + GridPane.getRowIndex(element));
                System.out.println("Column: " + GridPane.getColumnIndex(element));
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Great tips. I've decided to go into linking each button with one method onMouseClicked. Look at first post.